# How to assign variables in .env file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Q1.
I have a .env file in my ReactJS app like this:

```
API_1_ROOT='http://my-api-1.com'
API_2_ROOT='http://my-api-2.com'

BASE_API=API_1_ROOT   // This doesn't work as expected
```

I want to assign one of these api roots to my base api root; I tried doing this in my .env file but it doesn't work as expected.
How can I do this in my .env file?

Q2.
Also, I am not able to destructure multiple items from process.env like this:

```
const { API_1_ROOT, API_2_ROOT } = process.env;
```

When I'm doing this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I have to do this to get both variables:

```
const { API_1_ROOT } = process.env;
const { API_2_ROOT } = process.env;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Ask **one** question per question, not two. If you ask two, you will either not get answers to either because user X can answer one but not the other and so they don't post, or you'll get half-answers.

Comment: Re your second question: If your first code block gave you the error you describe, your second code block will as well. As long as you run your first code block server-side, in a file executed by Node (not the browser), you'll have a defined `process` object and will not get the error you describe (and the destructuring will work).

Comment: Re your first question, the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package used by create-react-app doesn't do variable expansion, but you can use [`dotenv-expand`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand) to add it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install dotenv --save`
2. Next add the following line to your app.

   `require('dotenv').config()`
3. Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it.

---

**.env**

```
// contents of .env 

REACT_APP_API_1_ROOT = 'my-secret-api-key'
REACT_APP_API_2_ROOT = 'my-secret-api-key'
```

---

**config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const config = {
  api1: process.env.REACT_APP_API_1_ROOT,
  api2: process.env.REACT_APP_API_2_ROOT,
}

export default config
```